# Changing the scale of yAxis on Highstock to draw plot line

Tags: highcharts

I have a data, say 200, that should be plotted as yAxis line.
The default min and max value is set to say 300 and 500 respectively.
How can i draw the yAxis plotline dynamically and how to change the scale of yAxis dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To add plotLine use `chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine(object)`. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.addPlotLine%28%29)

2) To change extremes use `chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)`. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes%28%29)